# Can I read signals from MiLight remote using nRF24L01+?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I'm planing to build my own LED controller for digital LED strips using Arduino Uno. I would like to control lights using external signals and also remote.

I have a MiLight remote that communicates with devices like bulbs, etc. on 2.4GHz. I have added nRF24L01+ to my Arduino and I would like to see if I can read data sent by remote.

I have found many examples on github of how to control MiLight devices (like bulbs) from Adrduino using RF24L01 (ex. https://github.com/DirkHeinke/arduino-milight) but I cannot find any example of how to read data sent by new remotes (all reverse engineered protocols are from more then 6 years and I guess they have modified the protocol / used channels / syncwords, etc.).

Related topics which doesn't seem to work anymore with new remotes:

https://arduino-projects4u.com/milight-rf-control/

http://arduino-projects4u.com/milight-new-protocol/

https://blog.christophermullins.com/2017/03/18/reverse-engineering-the-new-milightlimitlessled-2-4-ghz-protocol/

https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/39348/decoding-2-4g-rf-remote-controller

Comment: in your link https://arduino-projects4u.com/milight-rf-control/
you can find code to read remote data (title "show nRF24L01 decoding program"). have you try it ?

Comment: Yep, I have tried that with no success. The project is 6 years old and I guess they have changed the protocol / channels / syncwords since then. Using RF24 scanner (from https://github.com/nRF24/RF24) I can see traffic on channels mentioned in https://blog.christophermullins.com/2017/03/18/reverse-engineering-the-new-milightlimitlessled-2-4-ghz-protocol/ when using the remote (which indicates my setup is correct and my RF24L01+ works fine) but I cannot read any data.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day I have made it working. I have found similar topic in more suitable place so my answer is there: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/92655/89533